# How to identify files that have increasing numbers and a similar form of filename?

Tags: python, list, parsing, sequence, filenames

I have a directory of files, some of them image files. Some of those image files are a sequence of images. They could be named `image-000001.png`, `image-000002.png` and so on, or perhaps `001_sequence.png`, `002_sequence.png` etc.

How can we identify images that would, to a human, appear by their names to be fairly obviously in a sequence? This would mean identifying only those image filenames that have increasing numbers and all have a similar form of filename.

The similar part of the filename would not be pre-defined.

Comment: You can add your code to question and make it a good one! :)

Comment: Can you further explain what you want? Will the numbers always have the same number of digits? What do you mean by only image filenames that have increasing numbers? What if `image-000182.png` is missing? What does "similar" mean?

Comment: Rough sketch of an algorithm: 1) grep filenames with a pattern like "\w*\d+\w*.\w+"; 2) replace the "\d+" part with "_"; 3) group files where that form is equal; 4) check if the numbers are consecutive

Comment: @Kasramvd Getting a listing of files in a directory is very straightforward. It was the step immediately after this that I was not sure about, so there couldn't have been code to post in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: @Cyphase I don't have a very specific task in mind just now, but I have encountered many scripts that output files with filenames that are of varying forms but are still observably sequential by the incrementing numbers in their filenames. So, to answer your questions: The numbers should not always have the same number of digits. I mean only image files that are apparently sequences of files, ones that feature a continuous sequence of numbers. If a file in a sequence of files were missing, then two sequences would be identified. I mean "similar form" in the normal human perceptive sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to get files adhering to a certain pattern, e.g. `.*\d+.*\.(jpg|png)` for anything, then a number, then more anything, and an image extension.

```
files = ["image-000001.png", "image-000002.png", "001_sequence.png", 
         "002_sequence.png", "not an image 1.doc", "not an image 2.doc", 
         "other stuff.txt", "singular image.jpg"]

import re
image_files = [f for f in files if re.match(r".*\d+.*\.(jpg|png)", f)]
```

Now, group those image files by replacing the number with some generic string, e.g. `XXX`:

```
patterns = collections.defaultdict(list)
for f in image_files:
    p = re.sub("\d+", "XXX", f)
    patterns[p].append(f)
```

As a result, `patterns` is

```
{'image-XXX.png': ['image-000001.png', 'image-000002.png'], 
 'XXX_sequence.png': ['001_sequence.png', '002_sequence.png']}
```

Similarly, it should not be too hard to check whether all those numbers are consecutive, but maybe that's not really necessary after all. Note, however, that this will have problems discriminating numbered series such as `"series1_001.jpg"`, and `"series2_001.jpg"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear solution with detailed comments. I added a natural sort function for the lists in the resultant dictionary and the approach works nicely now.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to use `regex` trough files and group matching pattern with list of associated numbers from the file-name.

Once this is done, just loop trough the dictionnaries keys and ensure that count of elements is the same that the range of matched numbers.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from os import listdir

files = listdir("/the/path/")

found_patterns = defaultdict(list)
p = re.compile("(.*?)(\d+)(.*)\.png")

for f in files:
    if p.match(f):
        s = p.search(f)
        pattern = s.group(1) + "___" + s.group(3)
        num = int(s.group(2))
        found_patterns[pattern].append(num)

for pattern, found in found_patterns.items():
    mini, maxi = min(found), max(found)
    if len(found) == maxi - mini + 1:
        print("Pattern correct: %s" % pattern)
```

Of course, this will not work if there are some missing value but you can use some acceptance error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efficient solution. It helped me learn about regex.